# JProgressBar (setValue(0) мгновенно)

Tags: java, swing

Привет.

У меня есть очередь процессов, которые отображаются в прогресс баре. Но когда 1 процесс доходит до 100, я ставлю setValue(0), но мне нужно, чтобы прогресс бар обнулился сразу, а он как-то постепенно в обратную сторону уменьшается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setMaximum(0);
setValue(0);
setMaximum(100);
```

Больше решения не придумал.